# using variables with the system() function to call dos

Tags: operating-system, system, dos

I have been trying to write a simple brute force password cracker in C++ to open an old zip file that I locked a very long time ago.

I am trying to call pkunzip from the program.  The only way I know to do this is using the system() command.  As in system("astring");.  The problem is that I need to dump a new password into the string each time over and over until I get a hit.  That would require inserting a variable into to command that I am sending to DOS. That is where I get lost.  So the code could look something like this...

```
 system("pkunzip lockedFile -s[the password variable here]")
```

Also, this entire idea may be horrible, so if there is a better way then please just say.

Also, can I use a cd\ command to get to the proper directory, or do you just have to dump the relevant files in the same directory as the C++ project itself.  Any help or general pointers would be much appreciated.
m.hatter

Answer (score 1):

Would this do?

```
char buf[120];
sprintf(buf, "cd\\; pkunzip %s -s[%s]", locked_file, password_var);
system(buf)
```

I used the double backslash to escape into a single backslash for the `cd` command to work.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `sprintf` to create the string. As in:

```
command = sprintf("pkunzip lockedFile -s%s", password);
system(command);
```

If you're sick of calling this external program, you might want to handle the Zip file internally with a library like the [zip utils library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/zip_utils.aspx).

Comment: OK...both of these responses give me something to think about.  I will investigate.  Thanks!!!!